# Remove duplicate records in dataframe

Tags: r

I have created table with below values in R

```
Row 1 as ("Cat","Cat","Cow",NA)
Row 2 as ("Cat","Cow","Cat",NA)
Row 3 as ("Cat","Cat",NA,NA)
```

but I need my final output with all duplicate values in each row removed and also NA values removed 
output to read as below

```
Row 1 as ("Cat","Cow");
Row 2 as ("Cat","Cow"),
Row 3 as ("Cat"," " )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`), remove the duplicates (`!duplicated(x)`) and the NA (`!is.na(x)`), the output can be a `list` if the number of elements in each of the rows are of different `length` after the removal.  To convert it back to a `matrix`, we can pad blank values at the end using `stri_list2matrix` (from `stringi`).

```
lst <- apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) x[!is.na(x) & !duplicated(x)])
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(lst, fill='', byrow=TRUE)
#     [,1]  [,2] 
#[1,] "Cat" "Cow"
#[2,] "Cat" "Cow"
#[3,] "Cat" ""
```