# Remove Duplicates values in a Panda's Record

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates, distinct-values

I want to remove duplicates in each row for the column animals.

I need something like this post, but in python. I cannot figure this out right now for some reason and I am hitting a block.

[Remove duplicate records in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593699/remove-duplicate-records-in-dataframe)

I have tried using drop duplicates, unique, nunique, etc. No luck.

df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=False)
df

```py
df = pd.DataFrame ({'animals':['pink pig, pink pig, pink pig','brown cow, brown cow','pink pig, black cow','brown horse, pink pig, brown cow, black cow, brown cow']})

#input:
    animals
0   pink pig, pink pig, pink pig
1   brown cow, brown cow
2   pink pig, black cow
3   brown horse, pink pig, brown cow, black cow, brown cow
```

```py
#I would like the output to look like this:
    animals
0   pink pig
1   brown cow
2   pink pig, black cow
3   brown horse, pink pig, brown cow, black cow
```

Comment: `df.animals.str.findall("(\w+)").apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)))`? Note that this will fail when you have missing values. Missing values should always be treated with care :)

Comment: For what it's worth, `drop_duplicates()` is for removing duplicate rows, not values within a row/column (although you can restrict what columns to check)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'animals':['pink pig, pink pig, pink pig','brown cow, brown cow','pink pig, black cow','brown horse, pink pig, brown cow, black cow, brown cow']})


df['animals2'] = df.animals.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(set(x.split(', ')))))
```

Output:

```
0                                       pink pig
1                                      brown cow
2                            pink pig, black cow
3    brown cow, brown horse, pink pig, black cow
```

Explanation:

I turned your strings into a list. Then I turned the list into a set to remove duplicates. Then I turned the set into a list, and the I split the list turning it into a string again. Please tell me if something isn't clear!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I was trying something similar, but I missed the turning into a 'set' piece. Thanks again.

Comment: cool solution. I wonder if it will work if there is other datatypes than strings in the df ? I mean for example booleans and not nested lists or something complex

Comment: This solution applies only for string `Series`, if there's other columns with other datatypes it doesn't matter, though. You could also adapt the answer to work with `nan` values using `.loc`. You could also adapt it for nested lists

Comment: I noticed this may not work if the animals have colors. Such as 'pink pig' or 'brown cow' or 'black cow'. Is there a way to group the words between the commas?

Comment: So, if you have "brown cow" and "black cow" you want to keep both or just one?

Comment: If I had two instances of 'brown cow' it will keep both of them still. I tried changing the statement below, but that does not remove duplicates of single words. I then tried keeping both and that worked, but only some times... df['animals2'] = df.animals.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(set(x.split(',')))))

Comment: Could you update your question with your new problem and your new desired output? So it is easier to help you (:

Comment: My answer is still working for me, what are you getting differently?

Comment: Interesting... seems to be working. Must be something wrong with my side of things. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe your actual data isn't correctly splitted by " ,", or something like that

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to retain the original order of the items (converting to sets makes them unordered), the following function should work.

```
def drop_duplicates(items):
    # `items` is a comma separated string, e.g. "dog, dog, cat".
    result = []
    seen = set()
    for item in items.split(','):
        item = item.strip()
        if item not in seen:
            seen.update([item])
            result.append(item)
    return ', '.join(result)

>>> df['animals'].apply(drop_duplicates)
0                pig
1                cow
2           pig, cow
3    horse, pig, cow
Name: animals, dtype: object
```